# JSOUP 503 StatusCode Error

Tags: java, jsoup

I have the code below:

```
Connection.Response response = null; 
response = Jsoup.connect(URL1).ignoreContentType(true).timeout(10000).execute();
int statusCode = response.statusCode(); 
System.out.println(statusCode);

if (statusCode ==200){
     //do something
     } 

else {
    //do something
     }
```

The problem is I'm working with a server that often reports back 503s. When the status is 200, everything works fine. The statusCode is printed to the screen & the code below the if statement is executed. However, if the statusCode is 503, the statusCode is not printed to the screen & the else statement is not preformed at all... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I do no think it has anything to do with jsoup. the URL you are connection has got some capacity issues and server going out of service

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
response = Jsoup.connect(URL1).ignoreContentType(true).ignoreHttpErrors(true).timeout(10000).execute();
```

From the javadoc

```
ignoreHttpErrors(boolean ignoreHttpErrors) 
Configures the request to ignore HTTP errors in the response.
```